# Android Studio is not showing physical device Lenovo K5a040 (K3 Note) and have tried almost every method?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tried

1. Installing driver
2. The USB debugging enabled in Developer Options
3. Switched from MTP to PTP device selection
4. Check if `adb devices` command shows the devices
5. Edit Run Configurations.

But my physical device Lenovo K5a040 is still not shown.

Comment: Do you see your device on '$ adb devices'?

Comment: Did you hear any windows sound when connecting it to your PC?

Comment: yes i can hear windows sound and the phone memory and sd card memory are shown but device is not appearing in android studio

Comment: adb devices command doesnt show any devices even if the device is connected.

Comment: Alternative: If it's already rooted (i know, no ADB) you can try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of not properly installed  Android Debug Bridge (ADB) USB Driver on your system.

You can Check whether it is properly installed.

- Connect your Device and enable the USB debugging in device.
- Right click on My Computer and open the Manage.
- Go to other Devices and check whether your device is showing warning icon.(if it shows warning it is clearly says, ADB is not properly installed)
- Reinstall the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) USB Driver.

Please check this link it will be helpful.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows

Hope it will help. :-)

Comment: The link was really great and helpful! Thanks